# Pandas: Error when merging two tables, Error with set_index

Tags: pandas, merge, ipython

Thanks in advance for your help, here's my question:

I've successfully loaded my df in to ipython notebook and then I ran a group by on it:

```
station_count = station.groupby('landmark').count()
```

which produced a table like this:

[image]

Now I'm trying to merge it with another table:

```
dock_count_by_station = station.groupby('landmark').sum()
```

[image]

that is also a simple group by on the same table, but the merge produces an error:

TypeError: cannot concatenate a non-NDFrame object

with this code:

```
dock_count_by_station.merge(station_count)
```

I think the problem is that I need to set the index of the two tables before merging them but I keep getting this error for the code below:

pandas/index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:3979)()

pandas/index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:3843)()

pandas/hashtable.pyx in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas/hashtable.c:12265)()

pandas/hashtable.pyx in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas/hashtable.c:12216)()

KeyError: 'landmark'

station_count.set_index('landmark')

Comment: Please post `station_count.head().to_dict('list')` and `dock_count_by_station.head().to_dict('list')` so we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: station_count.head().to_dict('list')                                                   {'dockcount': [7, 5, 7, 35, 15],
 'installation': [7, 5, 7, 35, 15],
 'lat': [7, 5, 7, 35, 15],
 'long': [7, 5, 7, 35, 15],
 'name': [7, 5, 7, 35, 15],
 'station_id': [7, 5, 7, 35, 15]}

Comment: dock_count_by_station.head().to_dict('list')                                                       {'dockcount': [117, 75, 115, 665, 249],
 'lat': [261.76743300000004,
  187.19187299999999,
  262.40623200000005,
  1322.5692390000004,
  560.03989200000001],
 'long': [-854.6230119999999,
  -610.76793900000007,
  -855.602755,
  -4284.0548140000001,
  -1828.370075],
 'station_id': [210, 180, 224, 2126, 200]}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Using [join](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html)**

You can use [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html), which merges the tables on their index.  You may also wish to specify the join type (e.g. 'outer', 'inner', 'left' or 'right').  You have overlapping column names (e.g. station_id), so you need to specify a suffix.

```
>>> dock_count_by_station.join(station_count, rsuffix='_rhs')
               dockcount          lat         long  station_id  dockcount_rhs  installation  lat_rhs  long_rhs  name  station_id_rhs
landmark                                                                                                                            
Mountain View        117   261.767433  -854.623012         210              7             7        7         7     7               7
Palo Alto             75   187.191873  -610.767939         180              5             5        5         5     5               5
Redwood City         115   262.406232  -855.602755         224              7             7        7         7     7               7
San Francisco        665  1322.569239 -4284.054814        2126             35            35       35        35    35              35
San Jose             249   560.039892 -1828.370075         200             15            15       15        15    15              15
```

**Using [merge](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)**

Note that your `landmark` index was set by default when you did the `groupby`.  You can always use `as_index=False` if you don't want this to occur, but then you would have to use `merge` instead of `join`.

```
dock_count_by_station = station.groupby('landmark', as_index=False).sum()
station_count = station.groupby('landmark', as_index=False).count()

>>> dock_count_by_station.merge(station_count, on='landmark', suffixes=['_lhs', '_rhs'])
        landmark  dockcount_lhs      lat_lhs     long_lhs  station_id_lhs  dockcount_rhs  installation  lat_rhs  long_rhs  name  station_id_rhs
0  Mountain View            117   261.767433  -854.623012             210              7             7        7         7     7               7
1      Palo Alto             75   187.191873  -610.767939             180              5             5        5         5     5               5
2   Redwood City            115   262.406232  -855.602755             224              7             7        7         7     7               7
3  San Francisco            665  1322.569239 -4284.054814            2126             35            35       35        35    35              35
4       San Jose            249   560.039892 -1828.370075             200             15            15       15        15    15              15
```